# iOS SQLite database...pre-populate data

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I have a simple question & answers kind of data, and modeled it in XCode and have the classes working with relations defined as I needed (Each question has 4 answers, one of them is correct etc...)

Now the big task of putting all the questions I have prepared into the SQLite database on iOS.

What are the recommended and efficient ways to do this?

I can put the questions and answers in a text file (with some markers) and write a throwaway iOS code to read line by line and populate the database...but wanted to see here if someone recommends some other solution, before I start there.

I do NOT have the data in soft form at the moment, so I am open to anything. I started writing a desktop app (C#) to enter the data but would that desktop SQLite (on Windows) match with the iOS SQLite database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded BASE (http://menial.co.uk/software/base/) and populated my database in there.  The trial version works fine for import/export, just limits query results.

It even has an import from Excel function.  Although I find that was hard to get to work.  It was easier to write code in my Excel file to generate SQL statements, and then run those in BASE to create all the data I required.

Comment: Thanks, Base did exactly what I needed. Import a tab delimited file and then let me make minor edits before running it in a read only mode in my iOS app.

Comment: Yes, just what i needed. you will need to know the location of the db.... so it is ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/... on Yosemite it is very easy to get the logic. Just go to home folder (from finder), View--> Show View Options, and then tick 'Show Library Folder'.  You will get the logic.